# How to Use $_get in WordPress by PHP snippets

Tags: php, html, ajax, wordpress

I'm using WordPress and a plugin named "PHP snippets" to add my own coding in a WordPress page.

So, here is my code that I have added:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    showjob();
});
    function showjob() {    
    var intrest=document.getElementById("intrest").value; 
        jQuery.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'jobsloader.php',
            data: {
                intrest: intrest,
              <?php 
                 if ($_GET['type']=="need") //the problem starts here... No matter what is the value of type in url it is always echoing feed... even if there is no type in url it is echoing feed...
                 {
                   echo "type: 'need'";
                 }
                 else
                 {
                   echo "type: 'feed'";
                 }
              ?>
            },
            success: function(data) 
            {
                document.getElementById("addcontainer").innerHTML = data;
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

if you want more details, please ask in comments!

example: URL I was using was like this 
'http://www.abcd.in/bs/?type=need'

moreover I want 3  cases:

1. if there is type
2. if type=need
3. if type=feed

Comment: Welcome. So what's the problem? You didn't state it.

Comment: @jeto watch the code carefully i have added it in a comment

Comment: Do you have any type of caching plugin installed?

Comment: @user10280601 Indeed, sorry about that! Could you `var_dump($_GET['type'])` on top of the script and see what it contains for different URLs?

Comment: @Jeto var_dump is echoing NULL

Comment: @user10280601 With an URL like `http://www.abcd.in/bs/?type=need`? Then it must be related to Wordpress somehow. `$_REQUEST['type']` is the same I suppose?

Comment: @Jeto yes `var_dump($_REQUEST['type']);` is echoing same

Comment: @Jeto i knonw wordpress is somehow messing with it but how to solve this issue??

Comment: @Jamie_D no, I am not using any cache plugin

Comment: Maybe try `get_query_var('type')`. I know almost nothing about Wordpress though.

Comment: @Jeto `var_dump(get_query_var('type'));` results in -->  string(0) ""

Comment: @Jeto looks like this page know my problem but i didnt understood it https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with WordPress to give you solid help. Try to paste that code in the "Custom Query Vars" part of that doc and replace `my_var` with `type` maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not sure about your plugin, but correct way to pass data in GET request is : `http://www.abcd.in/bs.php?type=need`
or if implemented url rewriting then: `http://www.abcd.in/bs/need`

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress supresses GET variables for security purposes, so you must register them in either a plugin or your theme's functions.php file :

```
function custom_query_vars_filter($vars) {
 $vars[] .= 'need';
 $vars[] .= 'feed';
 return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'custom_query_vars_filter' );
```

Comment: my variable name is the type... and their values will be either feed or need so waht should i register need and feed or type???